# PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT

Tags: mysql, node.js, local

I made my project on c9 environnment, and i'm now trying to use it on local server.
My database is running on a personnal local server, which look like mamp, on 8080. 
My webserver on 8888.
The problem is that when I try to use mysql.createPool function, I have a timeout, with this error :

```
{ Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:160:17)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at Handshake.emit (events.js:185:7)
at Handshake._onTimeout (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:127:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
at Pool.getConnection (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
at /Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/routes/users.js:96:14
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/me/http/MyWebSite/matcha/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
fatal: true,
timeout: 10000 }
```

Here is my createPool function:

```
module.exports = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit: 100,
host: 'localhost',
port: 8080,
user: 'me',
password: ''});
```

I tried with and without password, on differents ports.
I found some issue about node 4.2 version but i'm using 7.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
{
        "host": "",
        "database": "",
        "user": "",
        "password": "",
        "port": 3306,
        "connectionLimit": 100,
        "queueLimit": 100,
        "acquireTimeout": 1000000,
        "connectTimeout": 30000,
        "debug": false
    },
```